# Working with DOM end events

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, dom, click

I have a small problem. If I have a form with few `inputs[type="text"]` and div's around them (plus and minus)... how to increment and decrement input without creating variables, classes, and ids for every tag? someone said I can use *arrays* but I don't know how to do it...

The example is with this type of solution - classes for every tag...

```js
var child = document.querySelector("#child");
var adult = document.querySelector("#adult");
var rooms = document.querySelector("#rooms");
var plusChild = document.querySelector(".plus_child");
var minusChild = document.querySelector(".minus_child");

var childV = child.value;
var adultV = adult.value;
var roomsV = rooms.value; 

plusChild.addEventListener("click", function(){
    if(childV<10){
        childV++;
        child.value = "" + childV;
    }
});

minusChild.addEventListener("click", function(){
    if(childV>0) {
        childV--;
        child.value = "" + childV;
    }
});
```

```css
.main-form {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.input {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 15px;
    background: none;
    outline: none;
}
.plus {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #999999;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
}
.minus {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #999999;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    
    <form action="" class="main-form">
        
        <div class="input-item">
        <span>child</span>
        <div class="toggle plus plus_child">+</div>
        <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="0" id="child">
        <div class="toggle minus minus_child">-</div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="input-item">
        <span>adult</span>
        <div class="toggle plus">+</div>
        <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="0" id="adult">
        <div class="toggle minus">-</div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="input-item">
        <span>rooms</span>
        <div class="toggle plus">+</div>
        <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="0" id="rooms">
        <div class="toggle minus">-</div>
        </div>
        
        
    </form>
    
    
   
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use 
var child= document.getElementById("child");
child.value++; or child.value--;

Answer (score 0):

It's all in a DOM tree. You don't need IDs on **EVERY** element you need to attach a handler to, you just need to know "where" it is in the tree, and go from a known point.

e.g.

```
<div id="attach_to_me">
   <button>+</button>
   <button>-</button>
</div>
```

Neither of those buttons "does" anything, but you can trivially have something like

```
$('#attach_to_me button').on('click', function(e) {
    char = this.text();
    if (char == '+') { do_plus(); }
    if (char == '-') { do_minus(); }
});
```

which is one single click handler, taking care of both buttons. If you need to know exactly WHICH button got clicked, `e.target` points at the element that was clicked. That gives you your starting point to look around the tree with. So if you had multiple buttons in multiple rows:

```
<tr>
   <td>foo</td><td><button>x</button></td>
   <td>bar</td><td><button>x</button></td>
   <td>baz</td><td><button>x</button></td>
</tr>

$('td button').on('click', function (e) {
    clicked_button = e.target;
    e.target.parentNode.previousSibling.text(); // `bar`
});
```

Use your known starting point of the button that was clicked, then move up/over in the tree to get the text in the neighboring `<td>`.

Comment: looks interesting... but how to write it in pure JS?

Comment: and I have a problem - if I use querySelectop it choose only first one, but with querySelectorAll it create array and script do "for" in the begining and after it buttons don't work... if i will do like this:

Comment: function clickFunction1(Element) { //do click handle stuff;}
function clickFunction2(Element) { //do click handle stuff;}
var textInputs = document.querySelectAll('input[type=text]');
for(var i=0; i < textInputs.length; i++) {
    textInputs[i].previousSibling.addEventListener('click',clickFunction1);
    textInputs[i].nextSibling.addEventListener('click',clickFunction2);
}

Answer (score 0):

You could use the previous and next sibling functions if you are sure that the html structure won't change.

Something like this:

```
function clickFunction1(Element) { //do click handle stuff;}
function clickFunction2(Element) { //do click handle stuff;}
var textInputs = document.querySelectAll('input[type=text]');
for(var i=0; i < textInputs.length; i++) {
    textInputs[i].previousSibling.addEventListener('click',clickFunction1);
    textInputs[i].nextSibling.addEventListener('click',clickFunction2);
}
```

Inside your clickFunctions you would need to reference the opposite previous/next sibling function to target the input.

Comment: the problem is that it just do "for" in the begining, but after it toggles don't work